# Using CURL in one of many dynamically loaded DLLs on same app

Tags: curl

I'm using CURL in a plug-in (which is a dll) loaded by a host, which in turn loads a bunch of other dlls. i have no control or knowledge if any other component loaded by the host uses CURL, or the order in which they are loaded/unloaded.
from what i gather, calling curl_global_init() multiple times is benign. however, i'm not sure about curl_global_cleanup() because of the following concerns:

1. calling curl_global_cleanup from my dll might prematurely terminate the CURL session for other components which are still using it.
2. other dlls calling curl_global_cleanup might prematurely terminate the CURL session while my dll is still using it.

the docs say that curl_global_init and curl_global_cleanup should be called once for all entities using the same memory space. does compiling /MT vs /MD might affect the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you need to do as many `cleanup`s as you did `init`s is exactly this: if two parts of the program use CURL, then you'll probably get two `init`s, and two `cleanup`s, and only the last `cleanup` will be destructive.

However, per the documentation, these calls are not thread-safe, which is something you may need to be aware of depending on how the other libraries (and your own) are designed.

There's no general answer to that, except to say, do everything you can not to interleave such calls. If that requires reading source code for the other libraries, then that's what you'll have to do. Hopefully, you'll find that they all abide by the following rule (again from [the documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl.html)):

> The basic rule for constructing a program that uses libcurl is this: Call curl_global_init, with a *CURL_GLOBAL_ALL* argument, immediately after the program starts, while it is still only one thread and before it uses libcurl at all. Call curl_global_cleanup immediately before the program exits, when the program is again only one thread and after its last use of libcurl.
>
> You can call both of these multiple times, as long as all calls meet these requirements and the number of calls to each is the same.

(The subsequent paragraphs go further than banning interleaving, actually recommending never calling `init` or `cleanup` while *any* other thread is in existence, whether it uses CURL or not. This is well-intentioned and technically correct, though perhaps a little over-aggressive depending on your point of view.)

Comment: thank you! i guess all i can do is stick to the best practices and keep my fingers crossed other developers of the host's plug-ins did the same. oh, and to wrap the curl_global_cleanup call in some try/catch wouldn't hurt in this situation...

Comment: @Lunch It's a C API so you're not going to get any exceptions.